# Forward from Macvlan Bridge to tun0 Inside Namespace

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables

Trying to isolate OpenVPN from host in a Namespace for only wireless clients.

Set up a namespace, added a veth pipe to the host, and iptable forwarded it with eth0.
The namespace VPN tested with pings through tun0 to the WAN and seems to be working.

For wlan0 to tun0 in namespace a macvlan with iptables looked promising.
Ping tests work between the wireless client and the namespace end (v-peer1) of the macvlan.

I can't get iptables to work between the macvlan v-wlan0 bridge end and tun0.

Can anyone help with this?

Here is the test script that is working except for the forwarding between v-wlan0 and tun0.

```
sudo ip netns del myvpn &> /dev/null
sudo ip netns add myvpn
sudo ip link add v-eth1 type veth peer name v-peer1
sudo ip link set v-peer1 netns myvpn
sudo ip addr add 10.200.1.1/24 dev v-eth1
sudo ip link set v-eth1 up
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ip addr add 10.200.1.2/24 dev v-peer1 broadcast 10.200.1.255
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ip link set v-peer1 up
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ip link set lo up
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ip route add default via 10.200.1.1

#   Forward eth0 <-> v-eth1
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.1.0/255.255.255.0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o v-eth1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i v-eth1 -j ACCEPT

#-----  Start VPN inside myvpn ///in another window while testing///
sudo ip netns exec myvpn sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp/ch201.nordvpn.com.udp.ovpn

#-----  Update myvpn/resolv.conf - add nameservers 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
sudo cp /etc/openvpn/resolv.for-myvpn /etc/netns/myvpn/resolv.conf

#-----  Create macvlan bridge
sudo ip link add v-wlan0 link wlan0 type macvlan mode bridge
sudo ip link set v-wlan0 netns myvpn
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev v-wlan0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ip link set v-wlan0 up

#-----  Ping tun0 by addr & name and v-wlan0 wireless client
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ping -c2 1.1.1.1 -I tun0
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ping -c2 amazon.com -I tun0
sudo ip netns exec myvpn ping -c2 192.168.1.118 -I v-wlan0

------  Set forwarding between v-wlan0 and tun0: ***NOT WORKING***
sudo ip netns exec myvpn sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo ip netns exec myvpn sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o v-wlan0 -j ACCEPT
sudo ip netns exec myvpn sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i v-wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several references say that MACVLAN is good for ethernet interfaces but that with wireless interfaces an IPVLAN L2 should be used.

I will assume that answer for this question to rework the script and test.